# How do I search a text keyword in a Facebook Page

Tags: facebook

I once liked one text post from one FB Page without clicking its like button (because basically I like every text post from this page).

Now, I have to refer that text post in my writing, but the thing is I forgot which post that has that text keyword, I tried searching that keyword by including the name of my FB Page and the keyword on the Search textbox at the right of Facebook's Earth icon, but that didn't work.

How can I search a text keyword in a Facebook Page? So that I can get its post, the one and only, just like when I got a twitter status that has the text keyword I searched.

Comment: I really haven't decoded what this "spotlight" is, but I found this kind of URL: `https://www.facebook.com/Sugarlanddonutsandmore/spotlight/?snippet_text=variety+of+donuts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the term you are searching for is pretty specific you could try:

- entering the search term in the Facebook search box.
- Select `See more results for %your search term%`
- Then in the left hand menu select `Public posts`

Answer (score 8):

1. From the page you're on, click on the Posts button in the sidebar, to the left.

[image: Posts button on sidebar]

You can then search for posts in the bar that appears on the right:

[image: Post search bar]

Comment: @downvoter: Why? This exactly answers the question.

Comment: Maybe it's what the OP meant when saying "the Search textbox at the right of Facebook's Earth icon" - I don't remember how the search in page looked 7 years ago

Comment: Maybe, but this actually helped me.  I don't know what the difference is between this answer and what the OP asked for (searching for a Facebook page for text keyword)

Answer (score 2):

I came across similar problem and thus created **[Advanced Facebook Search](http://advancedsearch.in)**  that **searches the News Feed of any Facebook page or a Friend or your News Feed** for a Query String and returns the search results **ordered by Likes, Shares, Creation Time or Comments Count**.

Searches are kept anonymous and the search data particular to a User is never stored in any Database. Have a look at the screenshot below or a give a try at

Link: **http://advancedsearch.in/**

[image]

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 2):

[image]

In a group, there's a Magnifying Glass icon in the top right-hand corner, near the 'settings' icon

Comment: And what does it do?

Comment: That only works for groups, not pages.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the normal search box on top of the page. Write your keyword and press enter.

On the left side of the results page, you will see a filter box with the title: "POSTS FROM". In this section, click "Choose a Source" and write the page that you want to search inside.

Answer (score -1):

Through Google. For instance, if you're looking for Facebook Italia posts, you should type the following search string on Google:
site:https://www.facebook.com/FacebookItalia followed by the words you're looking for.
The url is not always equal to the page name

Comment: Why was this downvoted?