# Is it possible to search for posts only from a particular Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-timeline

I was just wondering if it's possible to search for specific keywords in a Facebook wall of a certain page.

I found [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19559/how-do-i-search-a-text-keyword-in-a-facebook-page) but it is 3 1/2 years old now so I thought things might have changed.

Can this be done?

Comment: Welcome to Web Apps. Rather than open a new, duplicate question that may have out of date answers, the thing to do is add a bounty to the existing question with the "this question has out of date answers" reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it seems you can do it by doing regular searches like:

```
posts about "search term" by "page name"
```

The quotes aren't required, but you will get better results with them when your query and/or page name has more than one word.